# pySerial Capturing a long response

Tags: python, pyserial, modbus, pymodbus

Hi guys I'm working a on script that will get data from a host using the **Data Communications Standard** (*Developed by: Data Communication Standard Committee Lens Processing Division of The Vision Council*), by serial port and pass the data into **ModBus** Protocol for the device to perform it's operations.

Since I don't fiscally have access to the host machine I'm trying to develop  a secondary script to emulate the host. I am currently on the stage where I need to read a lot of information from the serial port and I get only part of the data. I was hoping to get the whole string sent on the **send_job()** function  on my host emulator script.

Guys also can any of you tell me if this would be a good approach? the only thing the machine is supposed to do is grab 2 values from the host response and assign them to two modbus holding registers.

**NOTE:** the initialization function is hard coded  because it will always be the same  and the actual response data will not matter except for status. Also the job request is hard coded i only pass the job # that i get from a modbus holding register, the exact logic on how the host resolved this should not  matter  i only need to send the job number scanned from the device in this format.

**main script:**

```
def request_job_modbus(job):
    data = F'[06][1c]req=33[0d][0a]job={job}[0d][0a][1e][1d]'.encode('ascii')
    writer(data)

def get_job_from_serial():
    response = serial_client.read_all()
    resp = response.decode()
    return resp




# TODO : SEND INIT SEQUENCE ONCE AND VERIFY IF REQUEST status=0
initiation_request()
init_response_status = get_init_status()
print('init method being active')
print(get_init_status())


while True:



  # TODO: get job request data
  job_serial = get_job_from_serial()
  print(job_serial)
```

host emulation script:

```
def send_job():
        job_response = '''[06][1c]ans=33[0d]job=30925[0d]status=0;"ok"[0d]do=l[0d]add=;2.50[0d]ar=1[0d]
                        bcerin=;3.93[0d]bcerup=;-2.97[0d]crib=;64.00[0d]do=l[0d]ellh=;64.00[0d]engmask=;613l[0d]
                        erdrin=;0.00[0d]erdrup=;10.00[0d]ernrin=;2.00[0d]ernrup=;-8.00[0d]ersgin=;0.00[0d]
                        ersgup=;4.00[0d]gax=;0.00[0d]gbasex=;-5.30[0d]gcrosx=;-7.96[0d]kprva=;275[0d]kprvm=;0.55[0d]
                        ldpath=\\uscqx-tcpmain-at\lds\iot\do\800468.sdf[0d]lmatid=;151[0d]lmatname=;f50[0d]
                        lnam=;vsp_basic_fh15[0d]sgerin=;0.00[0d]sgerup=;0.00[0d]sval=;5.18[0d]text_11=;[0d]
                        text_12=;[0d]tind=;1.53[0d][1e][1d]'''.encode('ascii')

        writer(job_response)


def get_init_request():
        req = p.readline()
        print(req)

        request = req.decode()[4:11]
        # print(request)

        if request == 'req=ini':
            print('request ==  req=ini??? <<<<<<< cumple condicion y enviala respuesta')
            send_init_response()
            send_job()


while True:


        # print(get_init_request())
        get_init_request()
```

**what I get in screen: main script**

```
init method being active
     bce
     erd
condition was met init status=0
outside loop
     ers
condition was met init status=0
inside while loop
trigger reset <<<--------------------
5782
                    `:lmatid=;151[0d]lmatname=;f50[0d]
                        lnam=;vsp_basic_fh15[0d]sgerin=;0.00[0d]sgerup=;0.00[0d]sval=;5.18[0d]text_11=;[0d]
                        text_12=;[0d]tind=;1.53[0d][1e][1d]
outside loop

condition was met init status=0
outside loop
```

**what I get in screen: host emulation script**

```
b'[1c]req=ini[0d][0a][1e][1d]'
request ==  req=ini??? <<<<<<< cumple condicion y enviala respuesta
b''
b'[06][1c]req=33[0d][0a]job=5782[0d][0a][1e][1d]'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Comment: Can you shrink this down to the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce your problem? It makes it much easier for us to debug with you, and I often find the process of boiling down a problem to it's essentials helps me find the issue myself. (help on creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @Aron, Sure will do!

Comment: @ Aron, Is this better ?

Comment: What serial library are you using? I'm not familiar with any `read_all` method from pyserial. In general I'm wondering how you intend to capture all the data. with the relatively slow rate of 9.6 kbaud, you may need to read for quite a while to make sure you capture all your output. Also, you may run into limitations with the buffer size of the tty device, so reading all in one go (single call to `read`) for this relatively large message.

Comment: @Aron, I'm using pyserial. initially I was using .readline() getting the same result. i tried read _all() just to try  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspect you're trying to write too much at once to a hardware buffer that is fairly small. Especially when dealing with low power hardware, assuming you can stuff an entire message into a buffer is not often correct. Even full modern PC's sometimes have very small buffers for legacy hardware like serial ports. You may find when you switch from development to actual hardware, that the RTS and DTR lines need to be used to determine when to send or receive data. This will be up to whoever designed the hardware unfortunately, as they are often also ignored.

I would try chunking your data transfer into smaller bits as a test to see if the whole message gets through. This is a quick and dirty first attempt that may have bugs, but it should get you down the right path:

```
def get_job_from_serial():
    response = b'' #buffer for response
    while True:
        try:
            response += serial_client.read() #read any available data or wait for timeout
            #this technically could only be reading 1 char at a time, but any 
            #remotely modern pc should easily keep up with 9600 baud
        except serial.SerialTimeoutException: #timeout probably means end of data
            #you could also presumably check the length of the buffer if it's always 
            #a fixed length to determine if the entire message has been sent yet.
            break
    return response

def writer(command):
    written = 0 #how many bytes have we actually written
    chunksize = 128 #the smaller you go, the less likely to overflow
                    # a buffer, but the slower you go.
    while written < len(command):
        #you presumably might have to wait for p.dtr() == True or similar
        #though it's just as likely to not have been implemented.
        written += p.write(command[written:written+chunksize]) 
    p.flush() #probably don't actually need this
```

P.S. I had to go to the source code for `p.read_all` (for some reason I couldn't find it online), and it does not do what I think you expect it does. The exact code for it is:

```
def read_all(self):
    """\
    Read all bytes currently available in the buffer of the OS.
    """
    return self.read(self.in_waiting)
```

There is no concept of waiting for a complete message, it just a shorthand for grab everything currently available.